# ¿Cómo hago un script en bash para utilizar el comando telnet en forma recursiva?

Tags: linux, bash, http, telnet

Quiero hacer un script en bash (un bucle sencillo) para probar un servidor en c que hice en linux (y se ejecuta localmente) y tengo un problema para hacer el "GET" de la petición HTTP. Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
echo GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1
done
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto en la consola me aparece:

```
./script.sh
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Y si escribo algo:

```
./script.sh
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
escribo algo y doy enter
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Not Found</h1>
  <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
 </body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Osea que se queda esperando el "GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1" aunque podemos ver que después lo imprime. Yo necesito que cuando se ejecute haga lo siguiente:

```
./script.sh
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1
```

Disculpen si no me explico bien pero soy nuevo en la comunidad.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo dónde estaría la forma recursiva que mencionás en el título

Comment: Quiero hacer un bucle usando telnet para ejecutarlo "n" veces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu script tiene dos problemas.

El primero está en la petición que realizas, porque la petición 'GET' debe finalizar con una línea en blanco. Por lo tanto, deberás modificar por 'echo GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n' (el primer 'enter' para enviar el GET y el segundo para la línea en blanco que cierra la petición).

El segundo está en la secuencia de comandos: hasta que no termine la ejecución de 'telnet' no se ejecuta 'echo'. Por lo tanto, deberás secuenciarlo con una tubería ('pipe'). También recomiendo agregarle una espera porque la ejecución de los comandos suele ser más rápida que la conexión del servidor.

Así te quedaría:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
(echo "GET /faca.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"; sleep 1) | telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción, es utilizar `wget`

> GNU Wget es una utilidad para descargar ficheros de la web. Soporta HTTP, HTTPS y FTP.

Es decir, con wget, podrás descargar la info de una web cualquiera, y descargarás todos sus archivos en el directorio de destino.

```
wget http://google.com
```

Y se descargará el index.html asociado a esa dirección.

Ahora, si lo quieres hacer recursivo, por ejemplo, para una lista de direcciones:

```
cat lista.dat
http://google.com
http://foo.web
-------
```

**script.sh:**

```
i=0
for a in `cat lista.dat`
do
  ((i++))
  mkdir $i
  wget $a
done
```

Esto creará un directorio para cada web, y descargará los ficheros asociados a la url. Espero te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas hacer la conexión varias veces puedes usar [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/) y puedes hacer la llamada de la siguiente manera:

```
~$ curl 127.0.0.1:8000
```

desde la terminal.

Comment: Claro pero la idea es hacerlo en bash usando "telnet" para simular una petición desde un navegador, no se si me explico.

Comment: Igual muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: con **curl** puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo (simular la llamada desde el browser), el problema de **telnet** es que va a dejar la conexión abierta hasta que la cierres manualmente con una combinación de teclas.